# Why SimpleRoundTo in Delphi 64bits fails to round a currency number properly?

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo, rounding-error

I'm wondering if there is any official and reliable Delphi function to round a currency as expected that doesn't change with the platform (without dealing with workarounds).

As "expected" I mean 0.5 round away from zero (rounded up) as we learnt from school and any mathematician will answer. You can argue a lot of technical explanation why it's "not possible/limitation of the language/platform" whatever in one way or another, but when users see an accounting report, they expect accuracy and consistency across the years and that's what we need from a developing tool.

This is a very old issue, more than 10 years. I thought Delphi had fixed the function SimpleRoundTo, and indeed they did it, as far as I can see in all the tests I made and in the discussion I found here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.delphi.non-technical/a_HLanoaOs8

I was convinced that after all these years, finally I was able to use the function SimpleRoundTo securely, but I was wrong.
I made several tests with positive and negative numbers that were previously reported as wrongly rounded using SimpleRoundTo.
All of them were rounded correctly using Delphi 10.2.3 (32bit) (On Windows 10 64bit).
But I found two values (at least) 79.615 and 4.225 which failed to round in the 64bit version of the function but are ok in the 32bit version.

As far as I understand, SimpleRoundTo is meant to do Arithmetic rounding, the one we learnt from school (not banking rounding like RoundTo does). 
The old fix to the SimpleRoundTo function had to do with the use of Double (wrong) instead of extended (correct) in the internal variable LFactor. 
I don't know in which version this was fixed, but at least for Delphi 7/2007 , SimpleRoundTo was screwed up according to the blog.

This is how the function looks in Delphi 10.2.3 and I guess since many versions back:

```
function SimpleRoundTo(const AValue: Extended; const ADigit: TRoundToRange = -2): Extended;
var
  LFactor: Extended;
begin
  LFactor := IntPower(10.0, ADigit);
  if AValue < 0 then
    Result := Int((AValue / LFactor) - 0.5) * LFactor
  else
    Result := Int((AValue / LFactor) + 0.5) * LFactor;
end;
```

This is the code I've been trying:

```
...
var
f1, fRes: Currency;
iR: TRoundingMode;
begin
    //Just to check, result is rmNearest
    iR:= GetRoundMode;

    f1:= 79.615
    fRes:= SimpleRoundTo(f1, -2);
    sValue:= CurrToStr(fRes);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(sValue);
end;
```

**Tested both positive and negative versions with the same results:**

79.614 Expected rounded value ---> 79.61  32bit ok | 64bit ok

79.615 Expected rounded value ---> 79.62  32bit ok | 64bit **WRONG (79.61)**

79.616 Expected rounded value ---> 79.62  32bit ok | 64bit ok

**All these values that were reported as wrong in the past, now are rounded correctly:**

1.234 Expected rounded value ---> 1.23   32bit ok | 64bit ok

1.235 Expected rounded value ---> 1.24   32bit ok | 64bit ok

1.236 Expected rounded value ---> 1.24   32bit ok | 64bit ok

1.664 Expected rounded value ---> 1.66   32bit ok | 64bit ok

1.665 Expected rounded value ---> 1.67   32bit ok | 64bit ok

1.666 Expected rounded value ---> 1.67   32bit ok | 64bit ok

79.624 Expected rounded value ---> 79.62  32bit ok | 64bit ok

79.625 Expected rounded value ---> 79.63  32bit ok | 64bit ok

79.626 Expected rounded value ---> 79.63  32bit ok | 64bit ok

79.634 Expected rounded value ---> 79.63  32bit ok | 64bit ok

79.635 Expected rounded value ---> 79.64  32bit ok | 64bit ok

79.636 Expected rounded value ---> 79.64  32bit ok | 64bit ok

87.284 Expected rounded value ---> 87.28  32bit ok | 64bit ok

87.285 Expected rounded value ---> 87.29  32bit ok | 64bit ok

87.286 Expected rounded value ---> 87.29  32bit ok | 64bit ok

I found one explanation of the behavior here: "On 64-bit Windows, the precision of floating-point operations with Extended variables is reduced to double precision."
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Delphi_Considerations_for_Multi-Device_Applications
but if the precision of a function depends on the platform, then we are lost, there is no reliable "native" cross platform function, no accuracy for a simple accounting report, it will change for ever as new platforms arrive. Maybe after all I'm doing things wrong?, it's not a bug, it's just the way it is and we have to live with. I refuse to do it, I expect certainties and I want to trust in the language.

Comment: "*The old fix to the SimpleRoundTo function had to do with the use of Double (wrong) instead of extended (correct) in the internal variable LFactor*" - in 32bit, `Extended` is a distinct 80..96-bit floating-point type (depending on platform). But in 64bit, `Extended` is just an alias for `Double`. See [The Extended Data Type is different on different platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Considerations_for_Multi-Device_Applications#The_Extended_Data_Type_is_different_on_different_platforms).

Comment: "*it's not a bug*" - sounds like a bug to me. "*I expect certainties and I want to trust in the language*" - then [file a report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) and be sure to include your test cases and results. There are already some other reports present ([RSP-13648](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13648), [RSP-15099](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15099), [RSP-20161](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20161), etc).

Comment: Thank you Remy for your answer, another bug report, ok. It's quite disappointing that after so many years we still have issues in Dephi with this matter, basic matters. I remember I was dealing with rounding issues in 2004 working in a project. At that time it was fixed with workarounds, then I just forgot and "archive" this topic in my procedures. 
I will create a file report and back here with a link when ready.

Comment: I've just created a file report in Embarcadero System Dashboard:
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-28268

Answer (score 3):

This is still an issue in **Delphi 10.4**, in that a `Double` variable containing 9.645 will `SimpleRoundTo` 9.64 but a constant value of 9.645 will `SimpleRoundTo` 9.65.

The problem seems to be that the `SimpleRoundTo` does not cater for the inaccuracy in storing float values.

Like you have for the `Extended` example, the `Double` overloaded version of `SimpleRoundTo` in the `Math` unit for **Delphi 10.4** is this:

```
function SimpleRoundTo(const AValue: Double; const ADigit: TRoundToRange = -2): Double;
var
  LFactor: Extended;
begin
  LFactor := IntPower(10.0, ADigit);
  if AValue < 0 then
    Result := Int((AValue / LFactor) - 0.5) * LFactor
  else
    Result := Int((AValue / LFactor) + 0.5) * LFactor;
end;
```

This was causing a lot of problems for us when the numbers coming out of our software were not as we expected, so we wrote our own.

This is the altered function that worked for us (we never use more than 8 decimal places):

```
function FnRound(const AValue: Double; const ADigit: TRoundToRange = -2): Double;
var
  LFactor: Extended;
begin
  LFactor := IntPower(10.0, ADigit);
  if AValue < 0 then
    Result := Int((AValue / LFactor) - (0.500000001)) * LFactor
  else
    Result := Int((AValue / LFactor) + (0.500000001)) * LFactor;
end;
```

You need to include the `Math` unit.